# Ordering database records by timestamp - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

For the query:

```
SELECT MAX(LOG_CREATION_DATE),COL_A, COL_B
FROM IMPORT_LOG
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(LOG_CREATION_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
              COL_A,
              COL_B
ORDER BY  MAX(LOG_CREATION_DATE)  DESC
              ;
```

the records are in descending order as needed:

```
09-FEB-12 12.59.18.000000000 PM
09-FEB-12 12.41.42.000000000 PM
09-FEB-12 11.26.15.000000000 AM
09-FEB-12 11.26.00.000000000 AM
01-FEB-12 01.27.11.000000000 PM
01-FEB-12 01.25.18.000000000 PM
01-FEB-12 01.25.17.000000000 PM
01-FEB-12 01.24.36.000000000 PM
25-JAN-12 02.39.11.000000000 PM
25-JAN-12 02.32.05.000000000 PM
25-JAN-12 02.31.37.000000000 PM
25-JAN-12 02.31.34.000000000 PM
```

But when I change the query to format the same timestamp column, the order completely changes to:

```
02-09-2012 12:02:18
02-09-2012 12:02:42
02-09-2012 11:02:15
02-09-2012 11:02:00
02-01-2012 01:02:11
02-01-2012 01:02:18
02-01-2012 01:02:17
02-01-2012 01:02:36
01-25-2012 02:01:11
01-25-2012 02:01:05
01-25-2012 02:01:37
01-25-2012 02:01:34
```

the updated query is

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(LOG_CREATION_DATE), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS'),COL_A, COL_B
FROM IMPORT_LOG
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(LOG_CREATION_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
              COL_A,
              COL_B
ORDER BY  MAX(LOG_CREATION_DATE)  DESC
              ;
```

why is the output changed ?

Comment: It looks like it's still ordered by descending timestamp, not by the character representation (assuming that all the `02` minutes are a typo).  Why on earth would you order your results by MDY?

Comment: `LOG_CREATION_DATE` is a timestamp field and the ordering is not done by MDY. What do you mean by "all the `02` minutes are a typo"?

Comment: Nothing is a typo in the results and exactly that's the reason I posted it. Why is the TO_CHAR() changing the timestamp and the ordering?

Comment: All the 'minutes' data is set to `02` or `01`, not the values in the previous list (that matches up with the seconds column); this means that your list appears to be wrong by the minutes, but matching it by second to the first column reveals that it's still sorted by a descending timestamp.  How did you want it sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format mask is wrong, you have the time part as `HH:MM:SS` when you should have `HH:MI:SS`. Or even better possibly, `HH24:MI:SS`.

Answer (score 4):

The ordering of your results hasn't changed; if you'll look a little closer at your results, you'll note that the date/second combination is unchanged.  This is mostly because in your `ORDER BY` statement, you're ordering by `LOG_CREATION_DATE` itself, and not a modified representation.

The error you're seeing is because you're telling the formatting string that you want **MONTH** twice - `MM` is *month*, and is **not** context dependent (use `MI` for minutes - sorry, I don't use Oracle, so it took me a second to catch this).

Here's the corrected statement - is this generating what you wanted?  Also, I don't recommend grouping by the character representation - use `TRUNC()` instead.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(log_creation_date), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS'), COL_A, COL_B 
FROM Import_Log 
GROUP BY TRUNC(log_creation_date), COL_A, COL_B 
ORDER BY  MAX(log_creation_date) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by a string representation of a date in a 12H calendar.  Your TO_CHAR is also incorrectly using MM twice.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT         TO_CHAR(MAX (LOG_CREATION_DATE) , 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS') AS CUSTOM_LOG_CREATION_DATE,
               USER,
               LOCATION,
               SUM(FILE_NAME) AS SUM_IMPORT
FROM           MYTABLE
GROUP BY      TO_CHAR(LOG_CREATION_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
              USER,
              LOCATION
ORDER BY MAX (LOG_CREATION_DATE) DESC
```

Comment: Its still not correct. I have updated my post with the order I am getting after making your changes

Comment: @darkie15 I modified my answer to take account of the format string error which some of the other answerers noticed.